# jQuery AJAX POST request to PHP must be submitted twice to work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

We are building a basic login form that redirects to different pages based on user credentials.

For some reason, we cannot get our login form to return an employee-type value and redirect to the proper page unless we submit the same information twice (the first time, it throws everything into the URL, kind of like a GET request, except that it's writing it to the URL before anything else, even the "#").

We are using Vue.js, but I don't know that it's really relevant to the issue at hand, except that it means the HTML and JS are in the same "component" file.

HTML:

```
<form class="login-form" id="loginform">
   <div class="form-group space">
      <label class="float-label" for="username">Username</label>
      <input type="username" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" >
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="float-label" for="username">Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" >
   </div>
   <div class="form-group"> 
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right" id="login">Log in</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
   $("#loginform").on('submit', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       console.log($('#loginform').serialize());
       $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'https://fleetr-208415.appspot.com/',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                var employeeId = data;
                console.log(employeeId);
                    if (employeeId == 1)
                {
                        adminScreen();
                }
                else if (employeeId == 2)
                {
                        dispatcherScreen();
                }
                else if (employeeId == 3)
                {
                        truckerScreen();
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("error");
                }
            }
        });
    });

})        

function truckerScreen()
{
        // similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
    window.location.replace("/#/trucker");
}

function dispatcherScreen()
{
        window.location.replace("/#/dispatch");
}

function adminScreen()
{
        window.location.replace("/#/admin");
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php header(“Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *“);
require ‘connection.php’;
$username = $_POST[‘username’];
$password = $_POST[‘password’];
$result = mysqli_query($conn, ‘select name, email, employee_type from employee where employee_id=“‘.$username.‘” and password=“‘.$password.‘“’);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1)
{
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $name = $row[“name”];
        $email = $row[“email”];
        $employee_type = $row[“employee_type”];
    }
    echo $employee_type;
}
?>
```

So if you were submitting username: James, and password: 123, on first submit the URL would become

> www.blahblah.net/?username=James&password=123#/login

And then, upon resubmitting the same information, you would be redirected to the proper page. Note that simply reloading the URL with the form information does not have the same effect.

Neither of us has any experience using PHP or AJAX for form submission/user validation, and we are at a total loss as to why this weird error is happening.

Comment: Why is the password ever passed as a GET on the URI? Clearly you are looking in POST, the Jquery also is POSTing...

Comment: We're never making a GET request, that's part of the problem. We have no idea why it's being written to the URL when it's being called as `type: POST`

Comment: So that means the jQuery code is not binding to the form and the form is submitting?

Comment: Any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: @epascarello that's where we're confused-- if it's that the jQuery is not binding, why does it work on the second submit, regardless of whether or not we leave the URL change intact?

Comment: `$(function () { console.log("UM", $("#loginform").length)`

Comment: @jeroen no, no errors.

Comment: Is your javascript after the form on the page or before like in the head or something.

Comment: I suppose it's technically after... vue.js makes it a little weird, as the <head> tag is in another page entirely, because it's component based. Login is just a component. The associated JS is injected at the end of the body.

Comment: Ah... honestly, without seeing all your code it's hard to know what is going on. The code itself looks fine... you may have to post more. I bet if you isolate the form and this code all by itself it'll work, which would point to your Vue code as the issue.

Comment: @epascarello on the initial submit nothing writes to the console, on the second submit length is given as "1"... but only if they're submitted within a minute or so of one another; otherwise, even though it works and redirects, it still writes nothing to the console.

Comment: So sounds like your JavaScript code is not written out so you need to figure out why

Comment: Sounds sort of like cache?

Comment: It would appear that Leeish is correct... when isolated from the Vue.js app, it works every time.

Comment: Now we just have to figure out why Vue is causing the problem -_-

Comment: For kicks is any of this form dynamically created? Maybe try changing to this `$(document).on('submit', '#loginform', function (e) {`

Comment: Also try and changing your URL to `https://fleetr-208415.appspot.com/index.php`. Sometimes slashes can change from POST to GET requests. Or just remove that last `/` and see what happens `https://fleetr-208415.appspot.com`